# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver even after using the mySql Maven Dependency on Intellij

Tags: java, mysql, maven, tomcat, jdbc

I am using Intellij for a servlet project and using maven

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
 </dependency>
```

as far as i know, this should handle all the classpath related issues when deploying the war on the tomcat webserver.

but i m getting

> 08-Apr-2017 13:40:37.047 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /Applications/tomcat/webapps/manager 08-Apr-2017
>   13:40:37.092 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /Applications/tomcat/webapps/manager has
>   finished in 44 ms java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   com.saurabh.testdb.TestDBServlet.doGet(TestDBServlet.java:34)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here is my code for loading the driver

```
package com.saurabh.testdb;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

@WebServlet("/TestDBServlet")
public class TestDBServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //set up connection variable
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false";
    String user = "springstudent";
    String pass = "sringstudent";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    try {

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        out.println("Connecting to database: " + jdbcUrl);

        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);

        out.println("Connection successful!!!");

        myConn.close();

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Class.forName(driver);` line hasn't been needed since 2006.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add your `jdbc_connector` to your tomcat server manually, you should to include your jar to this folder `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`

Comment: IT WORKED... but how ??IT WORKED... but how ?? Shouldn't the maven dependency take care of that?

Comment: yes, because Tomcat not include jdbc connectors to connect to your database, so you have to add it manually, so it can work with it @Saurabh

Comment: nope maven work with your application and not with your server @Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Just reproduced your bug. Seems like the name of the driver has changed in the new version. When you are downloading maven dependencies better be taking the latest Stable version - so you can have a better and faster support from the communities. `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
That is the error msg I've got:

Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: i'm using 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.6 i didn't get what modification are you suggesting here ?

Comment: it couldn't find this driver as well
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at com.saurabh.testdb.TestDBServlet.doGet(TestDBServlet.java:42)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for IntelliJ ultimate edition**

You can add your ***JDBC connector jar file*** to run configuration:

[image: Tomcat server run configuration]

Add the ***jar file***

[image: Adding jar files to application server library]

Or simply you can add the jar to `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`

Generally, the default path is `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib`

[image]

Invalidate caches and restart

Click [here on how to invalidate caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html)